# Pasar datos de datagridview a combobox

Tags: c#

C#
tengo una tabla con 3 campos llamados id_parentesco, descripcion y  Activo. Activo lo tengo en la tabla como bit y lo que me registra en la tabla es true\false.

Cuando inserto un nuevo registro este se registra sin problema en la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como hago para pasar datos de Datagridview a combobox ya que en los texbox cargo los datos de id y descripcion pero en el combo quiero insertar activo/ no activo o sea convertir el valor que tengo en la tabla que es true o false a Activo o No activo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando carga el form load yo cargo los datos del combo asi:

CmbEstado.Items.Add ("Activo");
CmbEstado.Items.Add("No Activo");
CmbEstado.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

pero se guardan como true o false en mi tabla.

saludos

Comment: No sé como estás recuperando los datos del `DatagridView`. Pudieras explorar las propiedades `DisplayMember` y `ValueMember` del combobox y trabajar en esa dirección.

Comment: En el datagridview asi lo tengo:  private void DGVParentesco_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
          
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    //gets a collection that contains all the rows                
                    
                    DataGridViewRow row = this.DGVParentesco.Rows[e.RowIndex]; CmbEstado.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() ;

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta para añadir ese codigo? Aqui en los comentarios no es muy recomendable postear código extenso. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes únicamente evalúa el booleano y mete una condición

```
private void dgvPrueba_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int Row = e.RowIndex; //Row en el cual te estas posicionando
        if (Row > -1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Row = this.dgvPrueba.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = Row.Cells[3] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            cmbPrueba.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToBoolean(check.Value) == true ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: el else if sobra en este caso.. si no es true, es false.. no va a ser null... los booleanos no son null..

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probare

Comment: Daniel este codigo que me distes donde lo puedo meter dentro del evento: CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)? La otra pregunta es que pongo dentro de los corchetes  Rows[Row].Cells[cell].Value

Comment: Claro puse el ejemplo

Comment: ami me funciono, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya probe este codigo que me distes pero veo que no pasa nada cuando selecciono en el datagridviedw:
private void dgvPrueba_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int Row = e.RowIndex; //Row en el cual te estas posicionando
        if (Row > -1)
        {
            bool datoEvaluar = (bool)dgvPrueba.Rows[Row].Cells[Cell].Value; //Cell equivale al nombre de tu columna "Activo" entre comillas dobles o puedes poner el indice con numero Ejemplo 2

```
        if (datoEvaluar) //Si es positivo ya que tu pones primero el activo en tu add item
        {
            cmbPrueba.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else //Si es falso
        {
            cmbPrueba.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

ni los texbox se llenan.

Answer (score 0):

asi lo tengo en el datagridview:

```
 private void DGVParentesco_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                //gets a collection that contains all the rows                

                DataGridViewRow row = this.DGVParentesco.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                //populate the textbox from specific value of the coordinates of column and row.
                TxtId.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                TxtParentesco.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = Row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            cmbPrueba.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToBoolean(check.Value) == true ? 0 : 1;


                //CmbEstado.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                //BtnEditar.Enabled = true;
                //BtnEliminar.Enabled = true;
            }


    }
```

pero no me pone nada en el combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Daniel espero estes bien

fijese que me da error en el codigo que me mando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que mas le hace falta a ese codigo.